# Raspberry Pi 4, Wifi connection not possible, interface not visible either, running OpenMediaVault on it

Tags: raspbian

I have a raspberry pi 4 and I installed OpenMediaVault on it. I have been using it with a LAN cable up until now, but I realised I want to configure wifi just in case I want to move it somewhere else where there is no LAN connection available. But to my surprise, I can't seem to find the wifi interface on it.

I included ifconfig where only eth0 and lo is configured.
I appreciate any help to point me to the right direction.

```
root@rp:/boot# ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.178.100  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.178.255
        ether dc:a6:32:0b:06:d1  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 4387  bytes 366501 (357.9 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 2326  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1323  bytes 304409 (297.2 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 631  bytes 64111 (62.6 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 631  bytes 64111 (62.6 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: What do you have in wpa_supplicant.conf?  Normally if any errors are in this it will not show up.  Also check config.txt and make sure it's not disabled in there.

Comment: Please execute this command, edit your question and add its output: `ip link`.